# Writing user input to a file in C

Tags: c

I am working on a program to write user input to a file and then search for a specific record in the file and output it to the screen. 
I tried using fgets and also fputs but havent been successful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main ()
  {
FILE *fileptr;
char id [30];
char name [47];
char amt[50];
int i;

fileptr=fopen("C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Documents\\Tester.txt","w");
 if (fileptr == NULL) {
     printf("File couldn't be opened\n\a\a");
     fclose(fileptr);
     exit(0);
  }

  printf("Enter name: \n");
  fscanf(fileptr,"%c",name);
  fputs(name,fileptr);
  fclose(fileptr);
  printf("File write was successful\n"); 
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong during posting. Please click `edit` to post your program (and perhaps describe what's "not working so well").

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried?

Comment: There is no code attached. Please improve your message.

Comment: sorry for the mistake.... i have added the code

Comment: why are you trying to close `fileptr` if it is `null`?

Comment: because if the file is null then you will not need it so u close it

Comment: this needs to be done to get 10 records, could a for loop work?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

1. You are trying to read from `fileptr`.
2. You are reading only one character, but treat the `name` array as if it was read in correctly.

A start would be:

```
  [...]
  printf("Enter name: \n");
  if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
    fputs(name,fileptr);
    fclose(fileptr);
    printf("File write was successful\n");
  } else {
    printf("Read error.\n");
  }
```

But that's not all: you have forgotten to put error checking. E.g., how do you know that your `"File write was successful\n"` if you don't check at least the return value of `fputs()`?

Comment: this needs to be done to get 10 records, could a for loop work?

Comment: 1. No, that could not work. Why do you want to read from `fileptr` which you have opened for `"w"`riting? I think you wanted to read from `stdin`? 2. A for loop would indeed work. But befor we are putting together fragments, you might want to define exactly what you try to achieve, so we can help "as a block".